# I'm rendering an absolutely positioned p element using JavaScript and I can't figure how to align it with the image above it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to achieve the following - whenever I hover over the image element I want to render the p element under the hovered image and programmatically set its top and left property so that it is completely aligned with the image above it. I've achieved most of it already, however, I can't figure out how to do the vertical alignment with the image. My current code results in this:

[image]

This is because I've set the left property to be equal to `this.eOffsetLeft = e.target.offsetLeft + width/2` which is the offsetLeft of the image + its width/2 which makes my test p element begin after the middle of the image. What I want is more or less this:

[image]

Is this achievable without too much hassle? Thanks for reading!

I have the following HTML in my template:

```
 <section class='skills'>
     <img @mouseover='displayAlt' @mouseleave='hover = false' src="#">
     <p v-if='hover' v-bind:style='{ "position": "absolute", "top": eOffsetTop + "px", "left": eOffsetLeft + "px" }'>Test</p>
 </section>
```

And the following JS in my script tag:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                hover: true,
                eOffsetTop: null,
                eOffsetLeft: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            displayAlt(e){
                this.hover = true;
                console.log(e)
                this.eOffsetTop = e.target.offsetTop + e.target.height + 40
                let width = e.target.width
                this.eOffsetLeft = e.target.offsetLeft + width/2

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak of @Steve's answer without JavaScript. Using CSS and `:hover` instead.

```css
section.skills {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

section.skills img {
  width: 100%;
}

section.skills p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

section.skills:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section class='skills'>
    <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/html5-topper.png">
    <p>Test</p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with vue.js.

However, using vanilla html, javascript and css you can do this (see snippet).

In css, you need to set the `position` of the parent element as `relative`. Then in the `p` set the `position: absolute;`. This allows you to position the element within the parent.

Then using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events within the `img` tag, you can position the `p` tag where you would like. Set the width of the `p` to the width of the image, and the top wherever you need. Because the `text-align` is set to `center`, the text will self align to the middle.

```js
function showP(x) {
  let p = document.querySelector("section.skills > p");
  p.style.display = 'block';
  p.style.width = x.width + 'px';
  p.style.top = x.height - 42 + 'px';
}

function hideP(x) {
  let p = document.querySelector("section.skills > p");
  p.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

section.skills p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section class='skills'>
    <img onmouseover="showP(this)" onmouseout="hideP(this)" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/html5-topper.png" height="200">
    <p>Test</p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to do this without javascript altogether using the `:hover` css selector.